# Force ConnectionError with Django cache in Tests

Tags: django, python-3.x, caching, testing

I have code which handles a `ConnectionError` when Django cannot connect to the Cache, which I'd like to test.

I've hit an issue that without actually disabling the real cache, I can't simulate it within the tests.

I have tried using the Django settings override:

```
with self.settings(CACHES={'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'}}):
```

However the above only simulates a cache, and not that it isn't available.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own cache backend that raises `ConnectionError`.

```
from django.core.cache.backends.base import BaseCache


class UnavailableCache(BaseCache):
    ...

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs)
        raise ConnectionError()
    ...
```

Then use this backend in `self.settings`:

```
with self.settings(CACHES={'default': {'BACKEND': 'path.to.UnavailableCache'}}):
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you